# Empty image when scraping using urllib in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/305196810048110603/f31411d41b42b65a0b6eca686dd67b08.webp?size=1024.jpg'
pic = open('abc.jpg', 'wb+')
pic.write(urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read())
pic.close()
```

So, I've browsed some questions on here and this is my current code which fakes a browser since discord doesn't like people downloading avatar pics.

The problem I'm having is that the image seems to be blank, which means that there is something wrong with my usage of urllib. I would appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the image in Chrome.  It seems to work fine there.  It seems the image is not actually a jpeg, but WEBPVP8/RIFF.  I haven't encountered that before.

Here is a page explaining how to convert riff files to jpg/png
http://www.freewaregenius.com/convert-webp-image-format-jpg-png-format/

I know there is a python-imagemagick library, that might be useful for automating / coding the conversion.